# IDE Question: Is there anyway to have a hierarchy view for my class's functions?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have been looking for quite a while every now and then for a way to get a hierarchy view for my Kotlin Class code in Android Studio/IntelliJ, but no googling has yielded any valid results.

This might be a silly question but it'd really help me focus with my code more. Is there any way that I can get a hierarchy map/view inside Android Studio for my class's and its functions and init variables ? My class has a HUGE amount of code lines and lots of functions. It just pains me to look for a function every time and I can't dock all functions every second I use them.

If there is no way to get a hierarchic way to look at it, I would love to know if there is any trick you guys use. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navigate | File Structure` (<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) will show an outline of the current file. You can also use the Structure tool window, which provides a similar view.